# Unable to build while using C# 7.0 features

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, roslyn, c#-7.0

Recently I pulled latest code on a project which compiles fine for some co-workers, but not for me.  There is a simple line in the code that causes it not to build:

```
if (x is null || y is null)
    return false;
```

gives me all these compile errors:

```
) expected 
Type Expected 
; expected 
Type expected 
; expected 
} expected
```

I feel that this is down to a compiler issue?  I am on *Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.6.3*, *.Net 4.7.03056*.  The project references **Microsoft.Net.Compilers 2.4.0** and in Properties > Build > Advanced it is set to **C# latest major version (default)**

I am not sure what I am missing to get this to build.  Comparing my environment to co-workers seems identical - any ideas?  Thank you.

EDIT: Can't change it to `==` as it is an override for `==` - plus this just avoids the situation and doesn't fix it.

Comment: What's the target framework version inside the `.csproj`?

Comment: <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>

Comment: @naspinski Try Latest *minor* version

Comment: You'll need to update the properties for your project to reflect what you're trying to do. Inside the projects properties, click on Application and select the appropriate Target Framework from the dropdown

Comment: Note that `is null` is `c#-7.0`, not `c#-6.0` as you wrote in the tags... And are you using `msbuild` or Visual Studio (because there is a tag)?

Comment: I will fix the tags, and I can't upgrade to 4.6.x yet

Comment: same errors with latest minor version selected

Comment: @naspinski Here it works... You could try uninstalling the package Compilers and reinstalling it

Comment: Or try compiling the solution with msbuild (from a command prompt of Visual Studio `msbuild yoursolution.sln` and try looking at the compiler it is using (you should see a `X:\solutionpath\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build..\tools\csc.exe`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my **.csproj** file, I had a couple rogue *if exists* imports that were placed there for whatever reason in the past.  Since they did not exist in my co-workers environments, it was not a problem for them.

```
 <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
 <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.3\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.3\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
 <Import Project="..\..\..\Dependencies\Packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.3\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\..\Dependencies\Packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.3\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
 <Import Project="..\..\..\Dependencies\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\..\Dependencies\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
```

I assume since the latter imports were a lower version, and happened to exist, they overrode the previous imports.

That said, I simply removed those two last imports and everything worked fine - thank you for the input everyone!

Comment: Still unclear why you should have a different csproj. The csproj is a file that is version controlled. Being different should have been a red flag.

Comment: It wasn't different, for whatever reason, they did not have the second directory present and I did.

Comment: And I see that there are some `Condition="Exists` so no error.